# Additional Constructor for Xtend @Data Value Object

Tags: java, xtext, value-objects, xtend

How can I add a secondary constructor to a Value Object (annotaded with @Data) in XTend (XText)?

I have tried the following, but it doesnt compile:

```
@Data class Dependency {
    val String groupId;
    val String artifactId;
    val String version;
    val String scope;

    new(String groupId, String artifactId, String version) {
        this(groupId, artifactId, version, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not possible. If there's already a constructor defined, the @Data annotation does not create a new one. You could use an custom Active Annotation to tailor the data class to your needs.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. Wouldn't it be nice to have the @Data annotation still create a primary constructor. I dont really see any scenario, where it would be usefull to not have the primary constructor being generated.

Comment: Yes, it would make sense to have the option to do so. Could you please file a ticket in the Xtend bugzilla?

Comment: Feature request is filed at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404793

Answer (score 1):

Althought technically not a constructor, you can create factory methods to instantiate your data class in multiple ways.